# How to ignore empty directory on bash mv in dockerfile?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

```
RUN mvn -B package
RUN java -Djarmode=layertools -jar target/*.jar extract --destination tmp/
RUN mkdir extract \
    && cp -r tmp/dependencies/* extract/ \
    && cp -r tmp/spring-boot-loader/* extract/ \
    #&& cp -r tmp/snapshot-dependencies/* extract/ \
    && cp -r tmp/application/* extract/
```

The above fails if I uncomment the `snapshot-dependencies` and the directory is empty.

Question: how can I tell dockerfile to ignore errors on this specific `cp` command if dir is empty?

Answer (score 0):

use `true` command

`cp -r tmp/snapshot-dependencies/* extract/ || true`